# Reducing long term unpredictability in pairs of crystal oscillators?

Tags: oscillator, low-power, crystal

We want to keep two physically separated units in sync with each other with the least drift between them possible. Absolute timekeeping accuracy is not important, only the relative drift between the two units.

Using off-the-shelf temperature compensated crystals ([example](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sitime/SIT1552AC-JE-DCC-32.768D/1473-1241-1-ND/5035516)), it is possible to get to about 2ppm over time periods greater than months.

I'd like to try to reduce that by characterizing and canceling the differences between the two crystals that contribute to that 2ppm drift.

Only one part I've found specifies the unit-to-unit variability in the data sheet, and interestingly that variability increases significantly after exposure to reflow temperatures...

[image]

So apparently exposure to high temps increases part-to-part variability, but why?

What are the other root sources of the drift between two temp compensated crystals? How can they be measured and (hopefully) canceled? Is it possible to buy or make crystals in pairs that minimize these sources of variation? Is there any other ultra low power (<10uA) oscillator types with lower unit-to-unit drift?

Note that in our case the units not subject to any acceleration except for constant G downwards.

This problem seems like something that would also come up in ultra low power communications systems where you want to receiver to wake up the *instant* before a transmission is expected and no sooner. Kind of like BLE power save RX windows, but on the order of months and years rather than milliseconds.

Comment: Are you talking radio comms or wired comms?

Comment: If you age and calibrate units after assembly but before going out in the field you can probably reduce that somewhat, but I don't think you are going to get sub PPM long term stability at microwatt power levels without external synchronization.

Comment: @Andyaka My application is not comms- just using that as an example of case when such remote paired clocks would be useful.

Comment: @Evan The above TXCO pulls <1uA and gets to about 1ppm general part-to-part variance and only costs ~$1. I was hoping that there is some room left for improvement that they just didn't bother to implement on such a cheap part. For example, I'd be happy to spend 10x for a 50% improvement. I just do not know where to apply more apply resources to have the biggest impact specifically on reducing the variability between two paired units. Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd try hand soldering the crystals with low temperature solder, if they are available in suitable packages, to reduce the destructive effects of reflow heating.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I am currently using conductive epoxy in the hope that no heat exposure will be best - but so far no enough data to know if it actually helps. Do you know fundamentally why heat exposure increases a crystal's variability?

Comment: I do not, though I have found crystal makers very knowledgeable and helpful - at least when dealing with a couple of companies based in Crewkerne, Somerset, England about 20 years ago. Also, big differences in (in my application, phase noise was the issue) between manufacturers. So, ask your supplier, and a few others, you may find one manufacturer who can help you or has superior products.

Answer (score 2):

For long term relative synchronicity you are better overall to find a way to link up each system to a reference on a periodic basis to null out long term drift. There will be a tradeoff in how often you do this versus the power consumed to do so and the money spent on circuit performance/complexity to achieve longer term uncoordinated sync.

Consideration should also be made toward realizing that matched components are never going to be perfect. As such you have to look toward higher level techniques to calibrate and null out undesirable characteristics.

Comment: Agreed! So far we have been unable to find a suitable reference source. The units can end up anywhere on earth so terrestrial WWV doesn't work, and units can be indoors so GPS seems unsuitable and also blows out thew power budget even if we only sync once per month.

We've tried to brainstorm other sources like ambient the 50/60Hz carrier or maybe even some extraterrestrial sources,  but so far can not find anything that works with these constraints. 

Other ideas welcome and appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @bigjosh if it is radio link then how long will it take your receiver to acclimatize to the prevailing radio transmission's amplitude. This is fundamentally important for a radio receiver and one one day it might have to deal with a signal that is -120 dBm yet on the next transmission it might be dealing with something at -30 dBm. This takes several milli seconds to accomplish and you have to factor this in thus making your precise timing really rather pointless. So, is it radio or not?

Comment: @Andyaka All true, but no matter what other factors you have to deal with, every microsecond early you wake up and start listing before the sender starts transmitting is wasted power! You actually pay double because if you wake up too late then you miss the transmission, so  you must take the maximum separation and start listing aggressively early.

Answer (score 0):

Tuning fork resonators have a 2nd order parabolic curve and compensation relies on the coefficients for offset (Tolerance=+/-5ppm) and stability df/dT with temp using a thermistor that has a linearized relationship with Temp, T.

The reason these are so popular is the flattest part of the temp curve is designed for 25'C close to wrist temperature for watches.

THe overall stability is defined in terms of Q of the resonator and VCXO's of 1 ppm are possible with slightly higher Q resonators such as AT cut crystals and >100 x higher Q, SC-cut crystals and when ovenized become 1e-11 or 10 ppb (not ppm) stable over temp.

THe AT std-cut crystals > 1MHz have a 3rd order T curve and may be customized to have the max-min range reduced over any temp, but typically done for -40~+70'C or 0~45'C etc as the **cut angle** affects each coeficient precisely measured in minutes ['] not degrees.  THese XTAL curves have been around for >50 yrs and I have used them to create parameters to predict the entire curve from the shift in the linear slope range e.g. 40~70'C to make 1ppm TCXO's with calibrated varicaps in uC controlled 1GHz radio with narrow spectrum.

Matching is unlikely unless everything is processed in the same batch.

The key to near-field communication is to have a PLL that reduces the system noise to the signal bandwidth which is likely much greater than 2ppm, but you want to be able to track the error by locking onto the received host before transmitting and maintain that correction during the transmission. Thus your error is now reduced to the error of the PLL which can be 0 and only now limited by phase noise, which multiplies with PLL frequency division, thus phase noise must be figured out and measured.

You can avoid reflow and attempt hand solder and try to see if there is improvement.

Unfortunately AT cut TCXO's need >=2mA unlike Tuning Fork resonators (xx uA) to get 1 ppm so the power cost is much higher with associated logic mA.

**I think if your requirement is micro-power and 1 ppm it is not achievable without RX ppm correction thus closed loop.**

Comment: Is the 1ppm limit for a tuning fork TXCO a hard limit? If so, where does that limit come from? The physics of the system?

Comment: Yea this is the residual from 2nd order (parabolic T) compensation from tolerances and higher order errors. Uncompensated would far greater

Comment: 1. If root of drift variance is all due to differences in temp response, would you expect that that frequency difference between two crystals kept at except identical temp would remain constant? Or maybe some linear drift due to aging, but that would be proportional to the original static difference in their frequencies?

Comment: 2. If drift variance at different temps is due to imperfect 2nd order modeling, then given high enough resolution samples (in both time and temp dimensions), then would you expect to be able to compensate better than 1ppm? How much better?  Do you know what the root source of the next limit of precision would be? Thanks!

Comment: aging is random due to contamination and leaching rate of electrodes into crystal, moisture ingress seals etc.  Considering 1ppm about bottom end for AT cut crystals which are higher Q, and stability is   inversely related  with Q and also non-linear with resonance and vibration or shock, from my experience, and thermal shock from spec experience. I don't see much point in guessing and you ought to test.  I have good experience on 3rd order AT cut polynomials but not quadratic 32kHz ones.  Packaging affects reliability, aging, and the best are ultrasonically welded, and vacuum sealed. ok?